# How to insert parameter into command in bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a bash script called `startserver.sh`.
I call it from another script like this:

```
sudo sh /opt/startserver.sh 400
```

I want to use the parameter `400` in `startserver.sh` like this:

```
java -Xmx400MB -jar craftbukkit-beta.jar
```

I tried:

```
java -Xmx"$(printf "$1")"MB -jar craftbukkit-beta.jar
```

but it did not work.

Of course, without the option `-Xmx....MB` it works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curly braces after the dollar sign allow you to expand a variable without putting spaces around it:

```
java -Xmx${1}MB -jar craftbukkit-beta.jar
```